# 301 Redirect from former .htaccess stuck

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

I uploaded a new Drupal 7 site to my server. The former non-Drupal php site used a 301 redirect in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] # force www prefix

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/main.php
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/main.php?section=$1&pageURL=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/main.php?pageURL=$1 [L]
```

The new .htaccess file contains none of the former Rewrite rules. The old one seems to be cached somewhere, and somehow that redirect is trapped.

When I load the home page the template loads, but then it doesn't load the new site's page content.

If I visit example.com/ I get:

Page Not Found
The requested page "/main.php" could not be found.

If I visit example.com/mypage I get:

Page Not Found
The requested page "/main.php?pageURL=mypage" could not be found.

I have no clue how to fix it. I see all of the newly designed site, but the main text content. I've tried everything I could find. Cleared my cache, flushed dns, private browsing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by un/reinstalling Nginx Admin.